# Get a centroid in QGIS via python

Tags: python, geometry, qgis, centroid

I am trying to get a centroid of a polygon in QGIS using python. Here is my code

```
layerPluto = iface.addVectorLayer("/path/to/mn_mappluto_16v1/MNMapPLUTO.shp", "PLUTO", "ogr")
features = layerPluto.getFeatures()
counter = 0
for feature in features:
    # Get the first feature from the layer
    if counter < 3:
        print feature['Address']
        print getCentroid(feature)
        counter += 1
```

... which gives me a "name 'getCentroid' is not defined" error.

I find this surprising, since the QGIS python editor has `getCentroid` as a dropdown syntax-completion option.

I also tried using this function as a method of the feature object via `feature.getCentroid()` and received a similar error ("'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'getCentroid'").

Similarly, trying `centroid(feature)` gives me the error "NameError: name 'centroid' is not defined," while `feature.centroid()` gives me  "'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'centroid'".

**Is there another method I should be using for this operation?**

Comment: check this post. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209292/getting-x-y-of-polygon-in-pyqgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[centroid()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a9af6067caef47d380d45c32569abc10b) is a method of QgsGeometry class.
You can retrieve the geometry section of a QgsFeature with [geometry()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#af516151bcf60aa1a31283ced4f7d9a9f) method
and so you can obtain centroid geometry siply chaining the two methods:

```
feature.geometry().centroid()
```